How to ask at interview why the position is still available when I know initial interviews took place 8 weeks ago?
looking for some pointers here on whether I should ask this question at all, and if so, how to phrase it.
I applied for a PA role three months ago, I was offered an interview 8 weeks ago, but was unable to attend as it was on the same day as my infant son’s very important hospital appointment that I had to attend and would’ve been detrimental to his health to re-arrange. They were unable to be flexible and offer me another date, but said they would keep my name and email on file should they not fill the position after the initial interview.
Six weeks go by and out of the blue I receive an email asking if I’m still interested in the position and would I like to come to an interview (scheduled for tomorrow).
I want to know why the position is still available. Is it that they were unable to find someone suitable out of those they interviewed eight weeks ago and it’s just taken them a long time to reach back out? Or did they appoint someone who then backed out for whatever reason before actually starting the position? Or did the person appointed start and leave/get let go extremely quickly? And if the latter - why? To my knowledge the position has not been re-advertised and the previous advert has expired/been closed on Indeed.
I basically want to know if I’m going to be potentially working for a nightmare boss who is impossible to please and will fire me/make life difficult. But I suppose if that’s the case they won’t say that even if I do ask.

At best, the answer you're going to be is " we haven't yet found anybody who is so completely outstanding that we had decided to stop interviewing.." at worst, the answer will be " why are you meddling in things that aren't your business?" There is really nothing to be gained by asking the question.

I wouldn't ask this question at all because they would think you're probably criticizing their hiring process.

The nightmare boss is just going to say they are a nightmare, simplest explanation, they didn’t hire anyone.

What does "PA" stand for ?

If they weren't flexible enough to reschedule an applicant they were looking for, how flexible will they be once you work for them? How they handle this flexibility when your kid has an appointment during working hours would be a way better question.

Most likely they didn't find someone they liked out of the first round of candidates, or maybe they did, but that person didn't accept the job. Sometimes it takes a long time to find the right person to fill a role. Eight weeks is nothing.

Do you have any evidence that they did hire someone initially for that position?  It more sounds like they had someone lined up with a conditional offer only for them to backout at the last minute (which happens), now they are back to interviewing.

This is like asking someone on a second date why they're still single. What good are you expecting to come of that question? You seem to be interested in whether you could ask it, but it's not quite clear why you think you should. (I know you listed your concern about a nightmare employer but it's not clear to me why you think you'd be getting a truthful answer that tells you what you need to know)

To piggy-back off the comment and answer:
Let us lay out the two possibilities as to the reason why:
Good reasons and Bad Reasons.
Good reasons could be things like they want to headhunt you, They hired someone else and immediately promoted them cause they were amazing (have seen it happen) etc.
Bad reasons could be things like low pay, bad work culture, high turnover, unrealistic expectations for the role...
All of which are things that a diligent interviewee should be able glean from the interview
And so - asking it outright is a non-starter. You can ask things like the Salary bracket, why the previous person left the role, what the responsibilities for the role, looking at the company on say Glassdoor, asking on LinkedIn - Hell, just looking at the faces of the people in the company when you walk in the door etc.
Therefore - if you want to ask that question, I would not suggest doing so, instead I would make sure I ask the questions around that question to fill in the blanks as best I can.

They might also have made an offer to their first choice applicant who eventually ended up turning down the offer  - so they had to circle back to the next-best set of applicants.  Or... it might be a bad company, so, as you say, be extra on the lookout for indicators of that.

Or maybe another manager needs a PA...

I kind of feel if it's a good answer they won't mind answering it and if it's a bad answer they'll mark you down for asking it...and you wouldn't want to work there anyway

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica That's where my mind headed as well.

The comment @Fe2O3 is very on point. Why ask a question that might be perceived negatively and can't be perceived positively. To what gain?
Leave it alone.
Bottomline, do you want the job or not? If you do, good luck.

Don't ask the question.
The answer is either:

We were unable to fill the position.

This could be for any number of reasons. But its balanced towards neutral.

bad pay (Negative)
person they wanted accepted a different offer (Different != better)
None of the candidates they interviewed passed the in person interview neutral
The person they hired quit (Probably negative, might not be.. maybe their mother got cancer, maybe they won the lottery... Who knows?)
The person they hired died (Might be negative, especially in Japan).
The person they hired was abducted by aliens
etc...


A new position opened up for the same/similar role and they had your resume on-file.

This happens, my team just did this. Getting resumes takes time/costs money, and their are so many trash applicants... It takes a lot less time/money to use a resume that already passed the filters than to start all over again from scratch.
No matter what the reason is the answer they give won't answer your question:

I basically want to know if I’m going to be potentially working for a nightmare boss who is impossible to please and will fire me/make life difficult. But I suppose if that’s the case they won’t say that even if I do ask.

As nightmare bosses tend to be egotistic narcissists who lie. Which means at best you get an honest answer or a lie, which you won't be able to tell apart. At worst you come off as rude and they cancel the interview.
Remember, an interview is a 2 way street. While you are interviewing with them, you are trying to sell yourself, sure. But they are also trying to sell themselves as a place that you would want to work for. Make sure that you want to buy what they are selling. Ask questions about expectations, what a career looks like working for them, try to find out what your boss is like, etc... Try to get a feel for them.
